# Can I run one way ANOVA at each of my time points?

Tags: time-series, anova, kruskal-wallis-test

Suppose that I have two or more groups of data (e.g. two or more cities with 10 sampled population each) and I want to test if they behave differently for a variable (e.g. specific crime) through the years.

Is it correct if I run one way ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis at each of the time points? I guess the answer is no because the time points are relevant to each other and not independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that a series of one-way ANOVAs is not the best way to model this. Instead, consider [repeated measures ANOVA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeated-measures), or a [mixed effects model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model). There are lots of resources for both on CV and elsewhere on the web.

Comment: I haven't read about mixed effects model yet, but considering the repeated measures ANOVA test, what is its non parametric equivalent? Friedman test does not take into account more than one group (city) concurrently.

Comment: That's a new question entirely ("what's a nonparametric alternative to a repeated measures ANOVA"), and probably worthy of its own post. The appropriate answer may depend in part on why you believe you need a nonparametric test.